# How to step out from a loop in PhpStorm?

Tags: debugging, phpstorm

While debugging, how to step out form a loop (`foreach`, `for`, `while`) in PhpStorm like what you do to step out from a function (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f8</kbd>)?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a single shortcut solution, but there is a simple workaround.

As stepping out of loop basically means you would execute the rest of the loop anyway, you can place the cursor after the loop and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to move to its position. This way you can skip all the loop iterations you don't want to inspect anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Set your next break point after loop and remove the break point in the loop and press F9